# Making a Javascript function work with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, dom-events

I have been trying to figure something out for a while and am not sure the best way to go about my current problem.  First I will let you know what I am trying to do.  A user enters text into a text box and then are brought to the next page where their input is split up into words and each word is turned into a link (the link will be a search but that does not matter at the moment).  The thing is that I want this to work with ajax.  Now I have the page with the textbox successfully using ajax to go to the "show" page, but I cannot find the best practice online for getting my Javascript that splits up the words to be executed alongside the ajax render call for "show".  Here is my current code.

The create form:

```
<%= form_for @icelandic_reader, :remote => true, :html => { :class => 'form-     horizontal' } do |f| %>
   <div class="control-group">
     <div class="controls">
       <%= f.text_area :text, :class => 'text_area' %>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-actions">
     <%= button_to 'Submit', icelandic_readers_path(@icelandic_reader.id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
     <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
            icelandic_readers_path, :class => 'btn' %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

create in the controller:

```
def create
  @icelandic_reader = IcelandicReader.new(params[:icelandic_reader])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @icelandic_reader.save
      format.html { redirect_to @icelandic_reader, notice: 'Icelandic reader was successfully created.' }
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @icelandic_reader, status: :created, location: @icelandic_reader }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @icelandic_reader.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

create.js.erb:

```
 $('.icelandic_reader').html ("<%=j render :partial => 'show' %>");
```

in the show partial:

```
<div id="icelandic_reader_text">

</div>
```

Show in the controller:

```
def show
  @icelandic_reader = IcelandicReader.find(params[:id])
  gon.icelandicText = @icelandic_reader.text

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @icelandic_reader }
  end
end
```

and finally the Javascript function I want to fill in the "icelandic_reader_text" div, which I currently have in icelandic_readers.js.erb:

```
window.onload = pageChecker;
function pageChecker() {
    var testElement = document.getElementById('icelandic_reader_text');

    if ( !testElement ){
        setTimeout(pageChecker, 50);
    }
    else {
        var myText = gon.icelandicText;
        console.log("test1");
        var words = myText.split(/[\s]+/);
        console.log("test2");
        var numWords = words.length;
        var textToInsert;

        for (var i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
            console.log("inside for loop");
            textToInsert += "<a href=#>" + words[i] + "</a>" + " ";
        }

    document.getElementById('icelandic_reader_text').innerHTML = textToInsert;
    }

}
```

The first part of the function before else I got from an answer here in stack overflow on how to get ajax to work with it, but it didn't work.  I am starting to think I have to implement in a different way than using `window.onload`.  I am kind of new to Ruby so I would just like to know if there is a different way of thinking I should be using for this problem.  Also I am using rails 3.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener to the form like this (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#icelandic_reader_form").bind('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {
      // code to execute after form successfully submitted
  });
}
```

I think the form id in my example is wrong, use the one given by rails.

Comment: that is not working for me.  After you type in 'ajax:success' in the function variables, am I supposed to be typing exactly what you put (data, status, xhr) or are those just guidelines of the kinds of things I should put?  Also, I am pretty sure it doesn't matter which javascript file you put this in because from what I gather ruby puts it all in one, but I tried to put this in both create.js.erb and icelandic_readers.js.erb.  And i did change the id of the form to be correct.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible be that `window.onload` is not triggering at all, or that its triggering before the `show` gets rendered, and therefore can't find the element `#icelandic_reader_text`

1. if you can, define `pageChecker()` in some file that you load in the layout so its ready to fire.
2. try this in **create.js.erb**:

   ```
   $('.icelandic_reader').html("<%=j render :partial => 'show' %>").each(pageChecker);
   //By chaining the actions with jquery, things should happen in the correct order.
   ```

You could also rewrite `pageChecker()`, where **`$(this)`** references **`$('.icelandic_reader')`**

```
    function pageChecker() {

        var myText = gon.icelandicText;
        console.log("test1");
        var words = myText.split(/[\s]+/);
        console.log("test2");
        var numWords = words.length;
        var textToInsert;

        for (var i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
            console.log("inside for loop");
            textToInsert += "<a href=#>" + words[i] + "</a>" + " ";
        }

        $(this).find('#icelandic_reader_text').append(textToInsert)
    }
```

Comment: neither one of these suggestions works :(  I have been trying them with minor variations for 2 days now and I can't find anything.  When I do your second suggestion (with (this)) it doesn't even show the text on the normal loading non ajax page.  I really just have no idea what to do to make this work.